# NodeJS Buffer.toString("ascii"), unable to search string

Tags: node.js

I'm using NodeJS and the "n-readlines" package to read a txt file line by line.
I then convert the read line to "ascii" and assign to a variable. But when I try to search a string from the readline, it doesn't seem to work even if the search string is present.

```
const nReadlines = require("n-readlines");

let line;

const lines = new nReadlines(File);
while ((line = lines.next())) {
    let nLine = line.toString('ascii');
    if (nLine.indexOf("SearchString") >= 0) {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

I suspect this has to do with the encoding? when I try to get substring with 4 as length, the returned string is just 2 characters.

What could be wrong here? Thanks.

Got the sample code above to readlines from this link:  [ReadLines](https://geshan.com.np/blog/2021/10/nodejs-read-file-line-by-line/)

EDIT:
Okay, I think I know where the problem is. The line read from the file is represented as multi-byte characters. Changing the code

```
line.toString('ascii')
```

To

```
line.toString('utf16le')
```

seems to solve my problem.

Comment: Try to do `console.log(nLine)` and see the output maybe?

Comment: I tried that and it prints like normal strings. But when I checked the value while debugging, the string displays like a double byte character, I can see space between characters.

Comment: Please paste the output of what you're saying in the question. It's difficult to say what's happening. The above code is running fine for me.

Comment: Thanks. So I just found out that the file I was parsing is not ANSI. Each character is represented as 2-bytes character. When converted buffer to string using 'ascii' encoding, I can that each character is followed by 0. I guess my problem now is how to convert this string to ANSI string.

Comment: When I console.log the line from buffer it would look like this:
Buffer(40) [255, 254, 83, 0, 89, 0, 83, 0, 84, 0, 69, 0, 77, 0, 32, 0, 73, 0, 78, 0, 70, 0, 79, 0, 82, 0, 77, 0, 65, 0, 84, 0, 73, 0, 79, 0, 78, 0, 13, 0, buffer: ArrayBuffer(8192), byteLength: 40, byteOffset: 0, length: 40, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Uint8Array']

After calling toString('ascii') it prints like this:
S Y S T E M  I N F O R M A T I O N
~SYSTEM INFORMATION

Comment: changing "line.toString('ascii)" to "line.toString('utf16le')" seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I know where the problem is. The line read from the file is represented as multi-byte characters. Changing the code

```
line.toString('ascii')
```

To

```
line.toString('utf16le')
```

seems to solve my problem.